# Radius of convergence of power series with integrals as coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Hi could anyone help me to solve this. Find the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(\int^{2n}_{n} \frac{e^t}{t}dt)y^n.$$

To find the radius of convergence, set $a_n = \int^{2n}_{n}\frac{e^t}{t}dt$ and wanted to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$. But all my attempt to integrate $\frac{e^t}{t}$ failed. I also tried using $\frac{e^t}{t} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{t^{n-1}}{n!}$ but it became much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $a_n$ is the coefficient of $y^{n}$ then $\frac  1 {2n} \int_n^{2n} e^{t} dt \leq a_n \leq \frac  1 n \int_n^{2n} e^{t} dt$. Take $n-$th roots and note that $(e^{2n}-e^{n})^{1/n}=e^{2}(1-\frac 1 {e^{n}})^{1/n} \to e^{2}$. By Squeeze Theorem we see that $a_n^{1/n} \to e^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @KaviRamaMurthy.  So I guess the radius of convergence is $e^{-2}.$

Comment: Yes, $e^{-2}$ is the radius of convergence.  @ChristopherCharles